# How to create a generator with recursion?

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, recursion, space-filling-curve

## Algorithm from Hacker's Delight 2nd Edition

## Ported to python

A simple Hilbert curve class.

```
class Hilbert():

    def __init__(self,order=1):
            
            self.x = -1 
            self.y = 0     
            self._step(0)
            self._hil(0, 1, order)
    
    def _hil(self, dirs, rot, order):
        if (order == 0): 
            return

        dirs += rot
        self._hil(dirs, -rot, (order-1))
        self._step(dirs)
        dirs -= rot
        self._hil(dirs, rot, (order-1))
        self._step(dirs)
        self._hil(dirs, rot, (order-1))
        dirs -= rot
        self._step(dirs)
        self._hil(dirs, -rot, (order-1))
         
        
    def _step(self, dirs):
        dirs %= 4
        
        if dirs == 0:
            self.x += 1
        elif dirs == 1:
            self.y += 1
        elif dirs == 2:
            self.x -= 1
        else:
            self.y -= 1 
        #prints all points 
        #print(self.x,self.y)
        #Could I "iterate" from here.
```

So what I want is something that gives a (x,y) every time next() is called. I tried doing this myself but can't get it to work so any help would be appreciated. Would I have to rewrite this to work with a generator?
[Source](http://www.hackersdelight.org/)

Comment: Are you trying to make `Hilbert._step` into a generator function (a function that returns a generator-iterator), or to make `Hilbert` itself into an iterator class (a class whose instances are iterators)? If you don't understand that question, just write us a couple of lines of code that show how you'd like to be able to use a `Hilbert` object.

Answer (score 1):

I think at least part of what you're trying to do is to turn `_hil` into a generator function, which yields the `x, y` pairs after each call to `_step`? If so, that's pretty easy.

The hard part is those recursive calls. But that's not really hard at all. That's exactly what [`yield from`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380) is for:* Take some iterator (like a recursive call to a generator function) and yield each of its values.**

Then there's the easy part, the non-recursive yielding of the `x, y` pairs after each call to `_step`. You can do that with an explicit `yield self.x, self.y` after each call. Or you can change `_step` to add a `return self.x, self.y`, so you can just `yield self._step(dirs)`. But you can also change `_step` to an iterator that only iterates one value, and then you can `yield from` it as well. (There's no real advantage to that here, but I think it's worth showing so you can think through how it works—especially since you asked "can I iterate from here?" in `_step`.)

```
def _hil(self, dirs, rot, order):
    if (order == 0): 
        return

    dirs += rot
    yield from self._hil(dirs, -rot, (order-1))
    yield from self._step(dirs)
    dirs -= rot
    yield from self._hil(dirs, rot, (order-1))
    yield from self._step(dirs)
    yield from self._hil(dirs, rot, (order-1))
    dirs -= rot
    yield from self._step(dirs)
    yield from self._hil(dirs, -rot, (order-1))

def _step(self, dirs):
    # existing code
    yield self.x, self.y
```

---

But now you've got that `__init__` that just calls `_hil` and does nothing with the result. That's not very useful. Maybe you're trying to turn the `Hilbert` class itself into an iterator class?

In that case, the easiest thing to do is store the generator iterator and delegate to it:

```
def __init__(self, order=1):
    self.x = -1 
    self.y = 0     
    self._step(0)
    self.iter = self._hil(0, 1, order)

def __iter__(self):
    return self

def __next__(self):
    return next(self.iter)
```

---

However, at this point, I'm not sure why you need this to be a class at all. The `x` and `y` aren't really part of the object's state, they're part of the generator state, which Python would take care of magically if you just used local variables in `_hil` (and normal parameter-and-return passing in `_step`). And the only other state is `self.iter`, which is only necessary because you're writing a class instead of a function.

---

<sub>* Actually, it turns out to be good for a lot more than that, as [Greg Ewing describes amazingly well](http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/greg.ewing/python/yield-from/); we wouldn't have [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) without it. But the original reason for adding it to the language was as "Syntax for Delegating to a Subgenerator".</sub>

** Note that this only works if you *have* `yield from`—meaning Python 3.3 or later. If you're still using Python 2.x, and `yield from` isn't enough to get you to upgrade, you can simulate *some* uses of it—including this one—by changing every `yield from eggs` into `for egg in eggs: yield egg`. It won't be as readable, and it will be significantly slower, but it will work.

Comment: Yes, like you said, I wanted to create a generator class. Your explanation was very helpful to me. Thank you.

Comment: @James: Part of the problem is that there is really no such thing as a generator class. You could argue that a class that fits the entire generator protocol (which includes `send` and `throw`) deserves to be called a generator class, but its instances still wouldn't pass, e.g., `inspect.isgenerator`. What you want is an _iterator_ class. Generators are a subtype of iterators, not the same thing.

Comment: @James: PS, don't feel too bad about not getting the terminology straight; people on python-dev and -ideas, even Python core devs, sometimes stumble over it. It's one of those cases where you so rarely actually need to name these things that it's hard to keep them straight…

Comment: Good question and intelligent answer.